# Html local storage saving data

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple main menu program.

**HOW IT WORKS:**

Simple, once you click level one and click on the done button, it unlocks level two, the problem is when you refresh the page it does not save it and level two is gone again.

**Code I've tried:**

I tried `HTML Local storage`, here are some examples I used

```
window.highestLevel = localStorage.getItem('highestLevel');
```

and stuff like that but I can't get it to save the level.

**Please help here is a link.** [***jsFiddle***](http://jsfiddle.net/ptcbkamx/1/)

Note: I want to use html local storage.

Comment: Please show the relevant code here, not just as a fiddle link.

Comment: should also show the code that wasn't working in demo. Not much good to troubleshoot code that already works

Answer (score 0):

Save it with

```
window.localStorage.setItem('highestLevel', window.higestLevel);
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you check that the browser you are working with supports localstorage. You could use [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/) or something to do that easily.

To set something in localstorage:

**javascript**

```
localStorage.setItem('your-identifier', your-data);
```

So for example, to save a user's name:

**javascript**

```
localStorage.setItem('username', 'Luke Skywalker');
```

To get "username" back from localstorage:

**javascript**

```
localStorage.getItem('username');
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use `getItem` (as you did in your question) when you load the page, and hide level 2 as needed:

```
if (localStorage.getItem("highestLevel") <= 1) {
    $("#level2").hide();
}
```

You'll also need to `setItem` to save when the user gets to level 2:

```
function mainMenuLvl2() {
    localStorage.setItem("highestLevel", 2)
    $('#level2').show();
}
```

Here's a JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ptcbkamx/2/

Answer (score 0):

You can use localStorage and sessionStorage to store your data on client side like below

```
localStorage.setItem("variablename","value"); //--> this value is object type anything
var storedValue = localStorage.getItem("variablename");
```

or

```
sessionStorage.setItem("variablename","value");
var storedValue = sessionStorage.getItem("variablename");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```js
localStorage.setItem("highestLevel", window.highestLevel);
```

Then, if you want to get the highest level, use this:

```js
localStorage.getItem("highestLevel", window.highestLevel);
```

I hope this helped!